# Highlight \n and %s "inside" strings

Tags: customize, faces

Is it possible for Emacs to highlight backslash escape (e.g. `\n`) and format keyword (e.g. `%s`) **inside string**, without messing up current modes' faces? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using library [Highlight](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary) ([highlight.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)).

Use command `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` (bound by default to `C-x X h x`), specifying a regexp that matches either or both things you want to highlight.  Examples:

- Interactively:

  ```
  C-x X h x \\. RET
  ```
- From Lisp:

  ```
  (hlt-highlight-regexp-region nil nil "\\\\." 'success)
  ```

Comment: I cannot find this function. And I don't sure if this is correct: `(hlt-highlight-regexp-region (point-min) (point-max) "\\." 'font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash)`. It not works...

Comment: Yes, that is the function. But in Lisp you have to double backslashes in strings (always) - use 4 backslashes in your sexp and it should work. If you call the command interactively, then you need only type 2 backslashes.

Comment: Is there any way to make it highlight automatically?

Comment: @kuanyui: You can put it on a mode hook, so it is invoked automatically.

Comment: You could also use the built-in hi-lock package, depending on your needs. The command `highlight-regexp` is bound to `M-s h r` by default. This operates on the whole buffer rather than the region.

Comment: @glucas: 1. Consider offering that as a separate answer. 2. `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` also operates on the whole buffer. It does so by default, i.e., when the region is not active. From Lisp, you can just pass `nil` as the first two args (`START` and `END`), to act on the whole buffer. 3. `hi-lock` highlighting is turned off if you turn off font-lock.

Comment: @Drew: Thanks, I'm not familiar with highlight.el so wasn't' sure what all the differences were. I'll check it out! Though I did just try turning off font-lock mode and my hi-lock highlighting was not removed / still works.

Comment: `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` renders `////.` incorrectly. But Emacs built-in `highlight-regexp` works well

Comment: But I have to say all the solutions highlight all backslashes, include the backslashes outside of strings....

Comment: @kuanyui: You say, "*hlt-highlight-regexp-region renders* `////.` *incorrectly.*" Please back that up with a recipe. Works fine as far as I can see. And if you really meant `\\\\.` then I see no difference wrt vanilla `highlight-regexp`.

Comment: @kuanyui: If you want to highlight a regexp only within certain contexts (e.g. strings) then you need to specify/control that. `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` does what it says: it highlights regexp matches in the region. Limit the region to a string and it will limit its highlighting to that string. It is a function; you can call it in your own code; use, for example, `narrow-to-region` to operate on specific strings, in a loop that advances over the area you want to affect.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in `hi-lock` feature to highlight patterns in the current buffer. As @Drew suggested in his answer, you can use this interactively or in a mode hook to highlight interesting patterns.

The command `highlight-regexp` is bound to `M-s h r` by default and prompts for a regular expression and a highlight color.

You can also define a mode hook to highlight patterns automatically. For example you can highlight alphabetic characters preceded by `\` or `%` in all programming modes using something like:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(lambda () 
        (highlight-regexp "%[[:alpha:]]\\|\\\\[[:alpha:]]")))
```

Comment: A faster regexp would be `\\(?:\\\\\\|%\\)[[:alpha:]]`, if I understand emacs' engine well enough.

Comment: Actually, using a `[%\\]` set for the first character might be best? `[%\\][[:alpha:]]`

Comment: Oh shoot, yeah.  Dunno how I forgot about `[ab]` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The following handles the basic case:

```
(defface my-backslash-escape-backslash-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash))
  "Face for the back-slash component of a back-slash escape."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface my-backslash-escape-char-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-regexp-grouping-construct))
  "Face for the charcter component of a back-slash escape."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface my-format-code-format-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-regexp-grouping-backslash))
  "Face for the % component of a printf format code."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defface my-format-code-directive-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-regexp-grouping-construct))
  "Face for the directive component of a printf format code."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)


(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
   '(("\\(\\\\\\)." 1 'my-backslash-escape-backslash-face prepend)
     ("\\\\\\(.\\)" 1 'my-backslash-escape-char-face      prepend)
     ("\\(%\\)."    1 'my-format-code-format-face         prepend)
     ("%\\(.\\)"    1 'my-format-code-directive-face      prepend)))
```

You don't often type backslash escapes outside of strings but a more elaborate regex might handle that.

Format specifiers have a lot of options so you might also want a more elaborate regex to handle those.

(Feel free to edit this if you're a regex ninja...)

Answer (score 2):

There's the highly incomplete [highlight-escape-sequences](https://github.com/dgutov/highlight-escape-sequences) package that does exactly that, it seems to support Ruby and Javascript only. It's one of the very many briefly illustrated packages from [Wilfred's guide to syntax highlighting](http://www.wilfred.me.uk/blog/2014/09/27/the-definitive-guide-to-syntax-highlighting/).

Comment: `highlight-escape-sequences` not works at all even if having set the `hes-simple-modes`.

Comment: You are aware `hes-simple-modes` is only set correctly via `customize`? If you want to avoid using it, you'd need to figure out the right instructions from the `:set` keyword in the customization code in the sources.

Comment: I found the problem, it doesn't accept `prog-mode`, but the real mode name like `emacs-lisp-mode`. Sadly, this cannot highlight string format keyword. :(

Comment: Sounds like an idea for a new package actually :)

Answer (score 0):

I took [Billy Highlights' solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2569/6987) and modified the regular expression so it would correctly capture the printf format based on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/). I used [this](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=3363) as a reference to get going.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'c-mode
  '(("\\(\\\\\\)." 1 'my-backslash-escape-backslash-face prepend)
    ("\\\\\\(.\\)" 1 'my-backslash-escape-char-face      prepend)
    ("\\(%\\)\\(\\(\\([-0 #\\+]\\)?\\([0-9]+\\|\\*\\)?\\(\\.\\*\\|\\.[0-9]+\\)?\\([hljztL]\\|l\\{2\\}\\|h\\{2\\}\\)?\\([diuoxXfFeEgGaAcspn]\\)\\)\\|%\\)"
      (1 'my-format-code-format-face         prepend)
      (2 'my-format-code-directive-face      prepend))))
```